# Commucation between a client software and a server software in C++ using multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, client-server, ipc

I have a software written in C++ that is gonna work as a server for several client softwares.

So each client program is gonna make a call to the server software and then the server software is gonna start a thread to serve the client.

The server and the clients might not necessarily  run on the same machine, but, in some situations, they will.

The main point here e having this server software being able to control the number of threads and calls, thus the centralization and also something that would be easy to reuse in various platforms and languages, so if I want to, I can write a Python or Java client to make a thread call and interact with the C++ server software.

I do have a C++ API built in but I do not know how I should proceed with this server/client architecture.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: as a side note, c++11 is much more supportive to multi-threading, are you using this or older c++?

Comment: It is the newest version, the point is not the multi-threading itself, but the communication between those threads and the client programs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're communicating locally I'd say the quickest suggestion is to brush up on [Remote Procedure Calls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4837/Introduction-to-RPC-Part). You should also be looking at [sockets](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) for connection across network between a server and a client.

These are broad topics so I would suggest that reading up on these will help you to find more direct questions than people can provide very specific answers to.

Comment: I do have some knowledge on sockets, my question is more about on having some people telling their experience solving this kind of problem and getting to know about other ways (libs, technologies, etc...) of implementing a solution.
Thank you for your reply.